# How to write builder pattern using java 8 lambda or lombok

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, lombok, javabuilders

I have pojo classes as shown below.

```
public class Car {
    private Engine engine;
    private List<Wheel> wheelList;
}
```

I am using Below pojo classes as parameters in "Car" pojo class.

```
public class Engine {
    private int power;
    private int type;
}

public class Wheel {
    private int size;
    private int type;
    private int colour;
}
```

Can you please help how to write builder pattern using java 8 lambda or lombok.

Comment: Do you have a plan of what you are doing? How do you want lambdas to fit in here? I'd recommend [reading up on the pattern first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). Right now this is basically another `plzsendtehcodez` question, and it isn't entirely clear what you want.

Comment: I'd recommend forgetting about lambdas for now.  Can you write the builder?   Do that first.

Comment: Prior to asking the question, please first research the topic and then come back with a question of you have a specific problem. There is at least 10 articles on using lambdas for builders when you google search "Java 8 lambda builder pattern" right on the first page of results.

Comment: Editing the question and title to include "or lombok" isn't going to change much - there is a lack of information here.

Answer (score 2):

> The builder patten is often used to construct objects with many
>   properties. It makes it easier to read initialisations by having
>   parameters named at the callsite, while helping you only allow the
>   construction of valid objects.
>
> Builder implementations tend to either rely on the constructed object
>   being mutable, and setting fields as you go, or on duplicating all the
>   settable fields within the builder.
>
> Since Java 8, I find myself frequently creating lightweight builders
>   by defining an interface for each initialisation stage.

*you should definitely read this -*

http://benjiweber.co.uk/blog/2014/11/02/builder-pattern-with-java-8-lambdas/